# JSF redirect to another page and open dialog

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, primefaces

I'm struggling now with redirecting. I want to redirect from one page to another with usage of h:commandButton / p:commandButton. And that works, but i need to pass an argument/ parameter with that request. And then use that parameter instantly after the new page reloads.

First page:

```
            <p:dataTable id="list" var="oneRow"
                         value="#{test.get_list()}" rowKey="#{oneRow.id}"
                         rows="15" paginator="true" paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                         paginatorPosition="bottom"
                         selection="#{test.oneRowObject}"
                         paginatorTemplate="{PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink}"
                         emptyMessage="----------" >

                <p:column selectionMode="single"/>

                <p:column headerText="ID" >
                    #{oneRow.getID()}
                </p:column>

            </p:dataTable>
```

And there is a commandButton which should redirect from page1 to page2, and in that page it should open dialogbox.

How can I do that? Do you have any suggestions or examples?

p - primefaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use `<f:param/>`

```
<h:commandButton value="Send" action="#{bean.method}">
    <f:param name="paramName" value="someValue" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Comment: Hi, I was trying to use that, but I'm having some problems to get the param value in bean (not the bean that is used in commandButton action attribute, but the bean that is used on the redirected page)

Comment: As for opening <p:dialog> after page loads I've used <p:remoteCommand> with option autoRun="true", works like a charm, and no JS needed :D

Comment: so I'm happy for you=)